# Como selecionar todas as colunas no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados

Como selecionar todas as colunas no banco de dados com os nomes 'nome' e 'data' tenho o código

```
<?php
    $sql = "??";
    if ($rs = $bd->query($sql)) {
      while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['data'];
        echo $row['nome'];
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Preciso, então, selecionar em todas as tabelas as colunas com estes nomes. Não sei se isso é possivel, ou eu vou ter que fazer isso um por um?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer o `SELECT` selecionando somente os campos **data** e **nome**:

```
SELECT nome,data FROM sua_tabela
```

E também você pode selecionar todas as colunas da tabela

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela
```

Caso queira selecionar essas mesmas colunas de todas as tabelas que você tem no banco de dados e exibir todos os resultados de uma vez, tente assim:

**PDO**

```
$query = $bd->query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){

  $tabela = $result[0];

  $sql = "SELECT nome, data FROM ".$tabela;
  if ($rs = $bd->query($sql)) {
      while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['data'];
        echo $row['nome'];
      }
    } 
  echo '<hr>';//Separa o resultado de cada coluna selecionada
}
```

**MySQLi**

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->conn, "SHOW TABLES");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

  $tabela = $result[0];

  $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT nome,data FROM ".$tabela);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    echo $row['data'];
    echo $row['nome'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Acho que vc não entendeu. Vou ser mais claro. Eu preciso selecionar essas duas colunas em todas as tabelas existentes no banco de dados (que no caso são só 6, porém todas possuem essas duas colunas). Acho que não seja possível fazer isso. Mas, se souber algum meio mais fácil do que selecionar tabela por tabela é bem-vindo

Comment: @DanielHeringer Editei, veja se é isso

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in C:\xampp\htdocs\JeanCarlos\index.php:116 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\JeanCarlos\index.php on line 116
A linha é essa:
while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){

Creio que seja por eu não estar usando conexão PDO e sim MySqli

Comment: Consegui! obrigado. Eu só troquei o indice do $result por "Tables_in_fotos" onde 'Fotos' é meu banco de dados

Comment: Ok. Se usar MySQLi coloquei uma opção pra você também usar ;)

Comment: Obrigado! Foi de muita ajuda.